# Display Image Rather than Text Javascript Function

Tags: javascript, html, web

Possible to display an image within these contexts without majorly editing the code. Usually you have:

```
(function() {
    popupShow("Loading...");
```

Makes a div popup with Loading... inside of it. Possible since this is HTML div to specify an image to show within this div rather than text? Crude but looking to manupulate without re writing, something to the effect of:

```
(function() {
    popupShow(<img src="img/video.png">);
```

Javascript for "popupShow"

```
function popupShow(text, buttonText, cb) {
    var saveBoxHeight = 60;
    var saveBoxWidth  = 380;

    if ((typeof buttonText)!="undefined") {
        saveBoxHeight+=30;
    }

    disableDiv = document.createElement('div');
    disableDiv.id = "DisableDiv";
    disableDiv.className="DisableDiv";
    disableDiv.style.cssText = "position:absolute; z-index: 120";
    disableDiv.style.width = window.document.documentElement.offsetWidth + "px";
    disableDiv.style.height = window.document.documentElement.offsetHeight + "px";

    disableDiv.style.top = "0px";
    disableDiv.style.left = "0px";

    newDiv = document.createElement('div');
    newDiv.id = "PopUpDiv";
    newDiv.className="PopUpDiv";
    newDiv.style.cssText = "position:fixed;background-color:white;font-size:35px;font-family:arial;border-style:groove; border-color:blue; z-index:121";
    newDiv.style.borderWidth  = "5px";
    newDiv.style.width  = saveBoxWidth + "px";
    newDiv.style.height = saveBoxHeight + "px";
    if ($.browser.msie) {
        newDiv.style.top  = (window.document.documentElement.offsetHeight - (saveBoxHeight*1))/2 + "px";
        newDiv.style.left = (window.document.documentElement.offsetWidth - (saveBoxWidth*1))/2 + "px";
    } else {
        newDiv.style.top  = (window.innerHeight - (saveBoxHeight*1))/2 + "px";
        newDiv.style.left = (window.innerWidth - (saveBoxWidth*1))/2 + "px";
    }
    titleDiv = document.createElement('div');
    titleDiv.style.cssText = "height:25px; color:white; font-size:18px; font-family:arial; background-color:#000099; text-align:right;";

    center = document.createElement('center');
    newSpan = document.createElement('span');
    newSpan.id = "PopUpText";

    newSpan.innerHTML = text;
    center.appendChild(newSpan);

    newDiv.style.margin = "10px 10px 10px 10px";
    newDiv.style.paddingTop = "8px";
    newDiv.appendChild(center);

    if ((typeof buttonText)!="undefined") {
        button = document.createElement("input");
        button.type="button";
        button.value=buttonText;
        button.style.cssText="position:absolute;right:10px;bottom:10px;";
        if (((typeof cb)!="undefined")&&(cb!=null)) {
            button.onclick=cb;
        }
        newDiv.appendChild(button);
    }

    document.body.appendChild(newDiv);
    document.body.appendChild(disableDiv);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you tried just by surrounding your html img tag ?

```
    (function() {
    popupShow('<img src="img/video.png">');
```